# confusion in what how to proceed in this probability question?

Tags: probability

A box contains three coins: two regular coins and one fake two-headed coin $(P(H)=1P(H)=1)$,

$a)$You pick a coin at random and toss it. What is the probability that it lands heads up?

B)You pick a coin at random and toss it, and get heads. What is the probability that it is the two-headed coin?

answer of a) can be calculated by applying the total probability law that the probability of $P(H)=P(H|I)P(I)+P(H|II)P(II)+P(H|III)P(III)$where the probability $P(I)$ gives the probability of picking u the coin I,II,III.

For calculating the second part

b)It asks for the probability  that given the toss is head what is the probability that it is the two head faced coin, I am sure that it is asking for the 
$P(III|H)$ then can I use the conditional probability formula to write the answer .
$$P(III|H)=P(III\cap H )/P(H)$$

Comment: I think the answer to the question in the last sentence is "yes", but it depends on whether "the conditional probability formula" that you are thinking of is the same one that I am thinking of. In questions like this I think it's better to actually write the formula so that we all know exactly which one is meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(\text{heads }\land\text{ two headed coin})=P(\text{heads }\mid\text{ two headed coin})\,P(\text{two headed coin})=1\cdot\frac13$
$P(\text{heads }\land\text{ normal coin})=P(\text{heads }\mid\text{ normal coin})\,P(\text{normal coin})=\frac12\cdot\frac23$

---

Part a:
$$
\begin{align}
P(\text{heads})
&=P(\text{heads }\land\text{ two headed coin})+P(\text{heads }\land\text{ normal coin})\\[3pt]
&=\frac13+\frac13\\[3pt]
&=\frac23
\end{align}
$$

---

Part b:
$$
\begin{align}
P(\text{two headed coin }\mid\text{ heads})
&=\frac{P(\text{heads }\land\text{ two headed coin})}{P(\text{heads})}\\
&=\frac{\frac13}{\frac23}\\[3pt]
&=\frac12
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 2):

There is a simpler argument to get the same answer:

- $6$ equally probable faces, of which
- $4$ equally probable heads, of which
- $2$ equally probable heads on the two-headed coin

a) The probability of heads is $\dfrac46$

b) Given heads, the probability of the two-headed coin is $\dfrac24$

Answer (score 1):

a)
$$
\underset{2/3}{\underbrace{P\left(\substack{\text{choosing}\\\text{a regular}\\\text{coin}}\right)}}\underset{1/2}{\underbrace{P\left(\substack{\text{flipping}\\\text{"heads"}}\ \big|\ \substack{\text{a regular coin}\\\text{has been chosen}}\right)}} + \underset{1/3}{\underbrace{P\left(\substack{\text{choosing}\\\text{the two-headed}\\\text{coin}}\right)}} = \frac{2}{3}
$$

b)
$$
P\left(\substack{\text{choosing}\\\text{the two-headed}\\\text{coin}}\ \big|\ \substack{\text{getting}\\\text{"heads"}}\right) = 
\frac{P\left(\substack{\text{choosing}\\\text{the two-headed}\\\text{coin}}\right)}{P\left(\substack{\text{getting}\\\text{"heads"}}\right)} = \frac{1/3}{2/3} = \frac{1}{2}$$